# Invalid SSL certificate on packagist.org when accessing from mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, browser, packagist

When accessing packagist.org from any browser i am getting this warning

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from packagist.org (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
packagist.org normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to packagist.org this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be packagist.org, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit packagist.org right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

the certificate is issued to

```
ISRG Root X1

L R3

www.rouleplaille.ovh

"Certifieate www.rouleplaille.ovh

Standard Issued by: R3
Expires: Monday 2 August 2021 at 20:24:48 Irish Standard Time
V This certificate is valid

Details

Subject Name
Common Name www.rouleplaille.ovh

Issuer Name 

Country or Region US
Organisation Let's Encrypt
Common Name R3
```

When accessing https://packagist.org from the android phone it's all fine so I suspect some settings on the mac itself. https://repo.packagist.org works no problem

curl output

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'packagist.org'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: What do `dscacheutil -q host -a name packagist.org` and `host packagist.org` print on your Mac?

Comment: ~ dscacheutil -q host -a name packagist.org
name: packagist.org
ipv6_address: 2001:41d0:701:1100::4f7e

name: packagist.org
ip_address: 51.38.227.34
~ host packagist.org
packagist.org has address 146.59.12.218
packagist.org has IPv6 address 2001:41d0:601:1100::4b27